# eigenvalues of a direct sum of matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-groups, cayley-graphs

According to Bacher's article, the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of Cayley graph of the symmetric group of order $n$ are $2-2\cos(\pi/n)$; my question is:

If we know that this adjacency matrix is comprised of a direct sum of matrices $B^{\lambda}$, where $\lambda$ is a partition of $n$, and we also know that the eigenvalues of a direct sum of matrices are the union of the eigenvalues of each of the matrices comprising the direct sum, then how do we assign Bacher's eigenvalues to each of the $B^{\lambda}$ matrices? How do we know each of the matrices' eigenvalues?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you include a link to Bacher's article?

Comment: Looks relevant : https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f016/ca63282139cd0f493e4c1cddc6e29c543a61.pdf

Comment: No comments ?...

Comment: Dear SirR. Bacher, Valeur propre minimale du laplacien de Coxeter pour le groupe symétrique

Comment: I was unable to find a link, but that is the name of the article. It is in French. Thank you

Comment: Thank you Mr. Marie. I am already in possession of the article you mentioned